# SELECT from two exclusive tables to combine the result set

Tags: php, mysql, select

My problem is that the website I'm currently working on has two tables for products and there's a search function that only searches one of the tables. I'd like to extend the search page of the website to cover both tables.

Effectively, I need two queries, which join their result set so I can use PHP to calculate relevancy to the user's search query.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE title LIKE '%$keyword%' OR content LIKE '%$keyword%'")
```

`title` is a field that is on the `product_spray` table as well, as is `content`. How can I modify the above query to include results from the `product` table and the `product_spray` table?

I'm not sure it's a JOIN that I need, because there's no link between the two tables, they're exclusive to each other. Though, I'm not very experienced with MySQL, so if there's something I'm missing, let me know.

I've tried this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product, product_spray WHERE product.title LIKE '%$keyword%' OR product.content LIKE '%$keyword%' OR product_spray.title LIKE '%$keyword%' OR product_spray.content LIKE '%$keyword%'")
```

The result set doesn't come out correctly, it seems to combine the results.

Essentially, what I need is to have a single query, but using two exclusive SELECT statements. Can this be done?

I'd even be open to doing something in PHP that will allow combining the result set of two queries.

Comment: Try UNION if the two tables are not linked. BUT field count must be the same in both, so SELECT * may not work if field count is different or changes in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to join the rows (*not the columns right?*). And to solve your problem, you will use `UNION` for this

```
SELECT  columnA
FROM    product
WHERE   title LIKE '%$keyword%' OR 
        content LIKE '%$keyword%'
UNION
SELECT  columnA
FROM    product_spray
WHERE   title LIKE '%$keyword%' OR 
        content LIKE '%$keyword%'
```

just make sure that both queries have the same column in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysq_query("SELECT A.*,B.* FROM 
product as A
left join product_spray as B ON B.title LIKE '%$keyword%' = A.title LIKE '%$keyword%' 
WHERE B.content LIKE '%$keyword%' OR B.content LIKE '%$keyword%'")
AND don't A.*  this sol - select A.title , A.content from xxx
```

Comment: The tables have no relation with each other